# What does it mean that Sync-gateway returns this error 401 Login required?

Tags: javascript, couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

Sync-gateway returns this error **401 Login required**, I don't understand why. Because I put in the header the basic auth with username and password, our root user to access to Couchbase.

I did a get on Sync-Gateway and it returns an error: *401 Login required*.

```
2019-09-16T07:53:07.554Z HTTP:  #9650: GET /bucket_01/_changes?style=all_docs&active_only=true&include_docs=true&feed=longpoll&since=603276
2019-09-16T07:53:07.554Z HTTP: #9650:     --> 401 Login required  (0.5 ms)
```

My Sync-Gateway configuration:

```
[...]
    "bucket_01" : {
      "server": "http://127.0.0.1:8091",
      "bucket":"bucket_01",
      "revs_limit": 20,
      "username": "admin",
      "password": "pwd",
      "users": { "GUEST": { "disabled": true } },
      "sync": [...],
    }
[...]
```

**UPDATE 18.09.2019**

```
[...]
    "bucket_01": {
      "server": "http://127.0.0.1:8091",
      "bucket":"bucket_01",
      "revs_limit": 20,
      "username": "admin",
      "password": "pwdAccess",
      "users": { "GUEST": { "disabled": true }, "admin": {"password": "pwd"} },
      "sync": `function(doc, oldDoc) { [...] }`
[...]
```

The call:

```
[...]
    var sync_gateway_url = 'http://our_server/db/bucket_01/'
    var querystring = 'style=all_docs&active_only=true&include_docs=true&feed=longpoll&since=0';
    var options = {
        url: sync_gateway_url + '_changes?' + querystring,
        auth: {
            user: 'admin',
            pass: 'pwd',
            sendImmediately: false
        },
        timeout: 10000,
    };
[...]
```

```
2019-09-18T16:07:39.526+02:00 [INF] HTTP:  #4205: GET /bucket_01/_changes?style=all_docs&active_only=true&include_docs=true&feed=longpoll&since=603372 (as GUEST)
2019-09-18T16:07:39.526+02:00 [INF] HTTP: #4205:     --> 401 Login required  (0.3 ms)
2019-09-18T16:07:39.532+02:00 [INF] HTTP:  #4206: GET /bucket_01/_changes?style=all_docs&active_only=true&include_docs=true&feed=longpoll&since=603372 (as admin)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where / how have you configured the sync gateway user ? Make sure that the user is configured via [sync gateway config](https://docs.couchbase.com/sync-gateway/2.6/config-properties.html#databases-foo_db-users) or via [REST API](https://docs.couchbase.com/sync-gateway/2.6/admin-rest-api.html#/user/post__db___user_). Confirm the list of users by doing a GET.

Comment: I use the same username and password in SyncGateway and in header of _changes, I have always the same error.

Comment: What you have configured is *not* the username/password of the sync gateway user. The username and password that you have in your config file is the credentials with which the sync gateway connects to the couchbase server. Configure the `users` property as specified in the [config docs](https://docs.couchbase.com/sync-gateway/2.6/config-properties.html#databases-foo_db-users) to correspond to the sync gateway user. Also, make sure you grant appropriate channel access.

Comment: I add the admin in "users" field in Syncgateway but returns the same error.

Comment: Share the snippet of sync gateway config that includes the change

Comment: I post it, take a look. Thank you for your support.

Comment: also post the curl command that you are using with the authorization header

Comment: I did it, do you need more?

Comment: What you posted does not include the HTTP headers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199639/discussion-between--and-rajagp).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the 401 error (Login required). I saw I done two calls one for the GUEST user and the other for Admin user. Admin user works fine but the other user fails and returns 401 error. I saw on the new sync_gateway 2.6 while in the previous versions I didn't see who I call or maybe I didn't set all the log keys on sync_gateway.